# How to arrange words in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-order

I have this sentence in english:

> Can I ask you one more question?

I am supposed to use *eine Frage stellen* instead of just *fragen*.

So I created this:

> Darf ich euch eine Frage stellen?

Is the position of *euch* correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct; I would ask *Darf ich NOCH eine Frage stellen?*, however (the addressee is somewhat obvious), simply to cover the *one more* aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can I ask you a question?** - Darf ich euch eine Frage stellen.

**Can I ask you one more question?** - Darf ich euch noch eine Frage stellen.

"Stellen" is a verb with 2 objects here, an accusative object (eine Frage) and a dative object (euch). Unless the accusative object is a personal pronoun or the accusative definite and the dative indefinite, the dative always comes before the accusative.

Beispiele:

- Ich stelle euch eine Frage.
- Ich stelle euch die Frage.
- Ich stelle sie euch.

---

- Ich stelle dem Mann eine Frage.
- Ich stelle dem Mann die Frage.
- Ich stelle die Frage einem Mann.
- Ich stelle sie einem Mann.
- Ich stelle sie dem Mann.

Also: "You" can be translated by "euch" (you guys), but also by "dir" (you, singular, informal) or "Ihnen" (you, singular or plural, formal).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.